# How do I effectively and safely insert records into database with foreign keys into SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, key

I'm writing a database in SQL Server, I have this [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYuQ2.png)

Basing on this, I've prepared [UML diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1pHO.png)

I have written SQL code to create tables and alter them with foreign keys

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Fname VARCHAR(20),
    Minit CHAR(1),
    Lname VARCHAR(30),
    Ssn VARCHAR(9) CONSTRAINT pk_Employee PRIMARY KEY, -- pk key
    Bdate DATE,
    Address VARCHAR(30),
    Sex CHAR(1),
    Salary INT,
    Super_ssn VARCHAR(9),
    Dno INT,
    CONSTRAINT chk_Employee_Ssn CHECK (LEN(Ssn)=9)
);

CREATE TABLE Department
(
    Dname VARCHAR(30),
    Dnumber INT CONSTRAINT pk_Department PRIMARY KEY, -- pk key
    Mgr_ssn VARCHAR(9),
    Mgr_start_date DATE,
    CONSTRAINT chk_Department_MgrSsn CHECK (LEN(Mgr_ssn)=9)
);

CREATE TABLE Dept_locations
(
    Dnumber INT,
    Dlocation VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT pk_Dept_locations PRIMARY KEY (Dnumber,Dlocation) -- pk key
);

CREATE TABLE Project
(
    Pname VARCHAR(20),
    Pnumber INT CONSTRAINT pk_Project PRIMARY KEY, -- pk key
    Plocation VARCHAR(30),
    Dnum INT
);

CREATE TABLE Works_on
(
    Essn VARCHAR(9),
    Pno INT,
    Hours DECIMAL(7,2),
    CONSTRAINT pk_WorksOn PRIMARY KEY (Essn,Pno),   -- pk key
    CONSTRAINT chk_WorksOn_Essn CHECK (LEN(Essn)=9)
);

CREATE TABLE Dependent
(
    Essn VARCHAR(9) ,
    Dependent_name VARCHAR(20),
    Sex CHAR(1),
    Bdate DATE,
    Relationship VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT pk_Dependent PRIMARY KEY (Essn,Dependent_name), -- pk key
    CONSTRAINT chk_Dependent_Essn CHECK (LEN(Essn)=9)
);

ALTER TABLE Dependent ADD
    CONSTRAINT fk_Dependent_Essn FOREIGN KEY (Essn) REFERENCES Employee(Ssn)

ALTER TABLE Department ADD
    CONSTRAINT fk_Department_MgrSsn FOREIGN KEY (Mgr_ssn) REFERENCES Employee(Ssn)

ALTER TABLE Employee ADD
    CONSTRAINT fk_Employee_SuperSsn FOREIGN KEY (Super_ssn) REFERENCES Employee(Ssn),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Employee_Dno FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)

ALTER TABLE Dept_locations ADD
    CONSTRAINT fk_DeptLocations_MgrSsn FOREIGN KEY (Dnumber) REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)

ALTER TABLE Project ADD
    CONSTRAINT fk_Project  FOREIGN KEY (Dnum) REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)

ALTER TABLE Works_on ADD
    CONSTRAINT fk_WorksOn_Essn  FOREIGN KEY (Essn) REFERENCES Employee(ssn),
    CONSTRAINT fk_WorksOn_Pno  FOREIGN KEY (Pno) REFERENCES Project(Pnumber)
```

Now when I'm trying to insert some data into those tables,

example:

```
INSERT INTO Employee(Fname, Minit, Lname, SSn, Bdate, Address, Sex, Salary, Super_ssn, Dno) 
VALUES ('John', 'B', 'Smith', '123456789', '1965-01-09', 'Lazy Town', 'M', 30000, '333445555', 5);
```

I realize that most of those tables requires foreign keys to any other tables, which makes the insertion very weird. To insert something, I must already have other data in the database. It's like vicious circle.

My question: is there any method to insert records in effective and safe way, without errors caused by non existing records?

EDIT:
I have tried to insert some data for any of those tables, using those commends (one after another, not all at once). Every time it failed, because foreign keys can't find records in other tables :<

```
INSERT INTO Employee(Fname,Minit,Lname,SSn,Bdate,Address,Sex,Salary,Super_ssn,Dno) VALUES
('John','B','Smith','123456789', '1965-01-09', 'Lazy Town', 'M', 30000, '333445555',5);

INSERT INTO Dept_locations(Dnumber,Dlocation) VALUES
    (1, 'Houston');

INSERT INTO Department(Dname,Dnumber,Mgr_ssn,Mgr_start_date) VALUES
    ('Research', 5, '333445555', '1988-05-22');

INSERT INTO Dependent(Essn,Dependent_name,Sex,Bdate,Relationship) VALUES
    ('333445555', 'Alice', 'F', '1986-04-05', 'Daughter');

INSERT INTO Works_on(Essn,Pno,Hours) VALUES
    ('333445555', 3, 10);

INSERT INTO PROJECT(Pname,Pnumber,Plocation,Dnum) VALUES
    ('ProductX', 1, 'Bellaire', 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @MertGülsoy, however, I need to note things out,

Your schema has 3 Main `PK` ( Employee.SSN, Department.Dnumber, Project.Pnumber). From these three PK, you'll have multiple relations that linked to them.

In SQL Server, the easiest method for your assignment is to create the tables first, then insert the data, then create the relations, which SQL Server will also check the existed data for the foreign keys.

Let's take a look on the foreign key Employee table (to understand the relations) :

Employee table

- [PK] SSN
- [FK] Super_ssn
- [FK] Dno

Each employee should have a unique SSN, but can share the same Super_ssn. I think the Super_ssn meant to be the Supervisor SSN. So, in this case, the supervisor needs to have a record in employees as well in order to relate to him. So, each Supervisor SSN you use in Super_ssn must existed in SSN as well (a separate record). Same thing on Dno, which related to Department table PK. each Dno, must be existed in Department.Dnumber as well.

So, the trick that you want to do in inserting Employees is to insert first the supervisor record, then insert each employee that is related to that supervisor record.

For instance :

```
INSERT INTO Employee(Fname,Minit,Lname,SSn,Bdate,Address,Sex,Salary,Super_ssn,Dno) VALUES
('John','B','Smith','123456789', '1965-01-09', 'Lazy Town', 'M', 30000, '333445555',NULL);
```

John's supervisor SSN is not existed, those, the relation will cause an error, and to fix it you need to insert supervisor first, then John, like this :

```
INSERT INTO Employee(Fname,Minit,Lname,SSn,Bdate,Address,Sex,Salary,Super_ssn,Dno) VALUES
('Mike','A','Tyson','333445555', '1965-01-09', 'Lazy Town', 'M', 50000, NULL,NULL),
('John','B','Smith','123456789', '1965-01-09', 'Lazy Town', 'M', 30000, '333445555',NULL);
```

Mike's Super_ssn has a NULL value, as there is no supervisor linked to Mike (he's the boss).

So, now your Super_ssn link is correct because `333445555` is existed on `SSN`, hint, Mike's SSN.

Note that we gave Dno NULL, because we haven't created the Department table yet.

You'll do the same with the rest of the tables, just ensure that each foreign key is existed on the main PK. As for your current INSERT data some of them lakes that.

Comment: Cool, I didn't even think about inserting nulls.

Answer (score 2):

Foreign keys are used for data consistency. These keys define relations between tables and you can see relations as a chain. So in order to add data to the structure, start by the beginning of the chain. For example, add the department first then add the employee into the department. There is no way to insert data in any linked table with a foreign key without following the chain.

Unless

If you drop/delete foreing keys, you can do inserts. But be careful! You can add the employee into the department which does not exist.

Edit:

`fk_Department_MgrSsn` and `fk_Employee_Dno` are circular references. You must delete one of them, possibly the `fk_Department_MgrSsn` and add a column to the `Employee` table named like *"isManager"* to carry the manager information.

Comment: can I remove foreign keys, add all the data and then add those foreign keys again?

Comment: No. The foreign keys will check for data validity when defined.

Comment: This chain has no beginning! Department can't be the beginning, because it needs foreign key to Employee. I don't know what to do

Comment: Thanks, it would work, but the I must follow the schema. I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys are there for something. If you want to be able to insert invalid data, then why you need foreign keys at all? Just delete them :)

However, foreign keys has state - they can be trusted or not. If you want to disable a foreign key, you can do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_MY_TABLE_SOME_COLUMN
```

You can also do this for all foreign keys in the table:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

This will preserve the foreign key, so you can find out where this column points to, but the data will not be validated and you can insert rows with missing values.

When you are ready to re-enable your foreign keys (if you want to), you can do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_MY_TABLE_SOME_COLUMN
```

Please note, that this command may fail if there are rows with invalid data.

About the efficiency, the most effective way to insert data usually is [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). If you do not specify CHECK_CONSTRAINTS, it will not obey your foreign keys when inserting data, thus it will make them untrusted. However, in your example you are using simple insert statements, so I guess you do not look for ways to insert millions of rows at once. In this case foreign keys should not affect your insert in terms of efficiency (except the inconvenience with the data consistency).

Answer (score 0):

See if data is populated from UI or web page level then simply design the page like that,

For Example to insert record in `Employee`,`SSN` and `DNO` both will be dropdown,so there is no question of Garbage data.

Suppose data is inserted from some other source then you can create `Instead of Trigger`.

If you bulk insert then you can use `Exists` clause to insert only those records whose FK value exists.

Other way of handling is to use TRY- CATCH.
So depending upon situation you can use any of those.

Don't disable `FK relation`.